# How to resolve Bit9 issue while running selenium script

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have selenium webdriver suite. It works fine for others but i am getting bit 9 issue while launching browser (IEDriverServer.exe).

Tools -> Internet Options -> Security, All zones are same settings and Browser is 100% zoom.

Any other solution is there?

Thanks

Comment: could you paste the stack-trace or complete error message so that we can help you further?

Comment: i don't have any stack trace. there is pop up that iedriverserver.exe is unapproved version..